# Highcharts call legend mouseover on custom legend

Tags: highcharts

I am working with a PieChart and have to render the legend separately and cannot use the normal PieChart legend. My legend is missing the *mouseover* and *onclick* functionality. Is there a way to call these functions from my custom legend?

Comment: Could you reproduce your code on some online editor which I could work on? I am not sure how your custom legend has been created.

Comment: Basically its a ReactComponent and hovering the component should execute the same function as hovering on the legend. Will prepare a JSFiddle for you.